# CSS - Background-image not showing

Tags: css, html

This is my CSS:

```
body {

text-align:center;
vertical-align:central;
width:480px;
height:800px;
}

#content {
width:100px;
height:200px;
background-image:url("../App_GlobalResources/TopBanner.png");
display:inline-block;
}
```

And my HTML (Master page):

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Mobile.master.cs" Inherits="m.mysite" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>TestTitle</title>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
    test1234
</div>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div id="content">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And i have a Default.aspx site which uses my masterpage, but it simple wont show my image..

if i make an img scr tag in the html it shows fine.. so the path is correct.. what else could it be? 
'
This is the output HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>
TestTitle
</title>
<link href="App_Themes/MobileTheme/MobileLayout.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />    </head>
<body>
<div id="header">
    test1234
</div>
<form method="post" action="" id="form1">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUKMTY1NDU2MTA1MmRkNWnHplPoHce7cSIeDENrnMaUn20Ibq7H6yKbaedCCPw=" />
</div>

<div id="content">

test

</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Look at the browser's developer tools' network tab. Does the image load properly?

Comment: Check if the url you're passing for the image is correct.

Comment: Also, please show the generated HTML, not the ASP code.

Comment: i've added the output html.. how do i see the browsers developer tools' network tab?

Comment: ah found the tab, and yes it loads the image..

Comment: oh wait a sec.. im getting an "not found" error..

Answer (score 0):

Okay it works now, seems like Internet explorer was looking in the wrong folder.. must be somekind om Visual studio bug/setting i diden't notice..